# Server cannot read data from PHP sockets

Tags: php, sockets

I am creating a command line PHP program that uses sockets to listen for  users connecting with telnet, reading commands to run on the server's database.

The question is I cannot get what is sent back to the server.  Here is the system code.

```
<?php

/*****************************************************************/
/*                                                               */
/*  Welcome to the ISH.                                          */
/*  You will need to configure this file to connect to Gen's     */
/*  Servers correctly.                                           */
/*  It is possible to be banned from this tool. Do NOT abuse it. */
/*  -Alex                                                        */
/*****************************************************************/

//Configuration
error_reporting(0);
$connection_ip = "*****";
$connection_port = 43597;
$max_clients = 10;

$Server = new GenISH();
$Server->databaseConnect();
$Server->connect();
$Server->bind();
$Server->listen();
$Server->MainLoop();

class GenISH
{
    public $connection_ip;
    public $connection_port;
    public $socket;
    public $max_clients;
    public $read;
    public $connected_clients;
    public $databaseConnection;

    //User data
    public $username;

    public function checkBanned($ip)
    {
        $query = mysqli_query($this->databaseConnection, "SELECT * FROM `ish_bans` WHERE `ip` = '$ip'");
        if(mysqli_num_rows($query) >= 1)
        {
            return true;
        }else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function getBanReason($ip)
    {
        $query = mysqli_query($this->databaseConnection, "SELECT * FROM `ish_bans` WHERE `ip` = '$ip'") or die(mysqli_error($this->databaseConnection));
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
        return $row["reason"];
    }

    public function databaseConnect()
    {
        $this->databaseConnection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "GenDatabase123", "gen");
        echo "Server: Connected to database\n";
    }

    public function showError($error)
    {
        $ec = socket_last_error();
        $errmsg = socket_strerror($ec);
        echo $error = "Error! Could not $error socket! [$ec] $errmsg";
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        global $connection_ip, $connection_port, $max_clients;
        $this->connection_ip = $connection_ip;
        $this->connection_port = $connection_port;
        $this->max_clients = $max_clients;
    }

    public function connect()
    {
        echo "Server: Connecting!\n";
        if(!($this->socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)))
        {
            $this->showError("connect");
        }else
        {
            echo "Server: Connected!\n";
        }
    }

    public function bind()
    {
        echo "Server: binding socket!\n";
        if(!(socket_bind($this->socket, $this->connection_ip, $this->connection_port)))
        {
            echo "Server: Failed to bind!\n";
        }else
        {
            echo "Server: Socket bind successful!\n";
        }
    }

    public function listen()
    {
        if(!(socket_listen($this->socket, 10)))
        {
            echo "Server: Failed to listen on socket!\n";
        }else
        {
            echo "Server: Initialization complete!\nServer: Listening for connections on port $this->connection_port!\n";
        }
    }

    public function send($client, $message)
    {
        socket_write($client, $message);
    }

    public function getUserData($client)
    {
        $query = mysqli_query($this->databaseConnection, "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `ip_last` = '$client'");
        if(mysqli_num_rows($query) <= 0)
        {
            $this->username = "Unkown...";
        }else
        {
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
            $this->username = $row["username"];
        }
    }

    public function MainLoop()
    {
        $this->read = array();
        $this->connected_clients = array();

        while(true)
        {
            $this->read = array();

            //Set Master socket
            $this->read[0] = $this->socket;

            for($i = 0; $i < $this->max_clients; $i++)
            {
                if($this->connected_clients[$i] != null)
                {
                    //An exmple of how this works is
                    //this adds one to the read and makes it equal to the connected client.
                    $this->read[$i+1] = $this->connected_clients[$i];
                }
            }

            if(socket_select($this->read, $write, $except, null) == false)
            {
                $this->showError("listen on");
            }

            if(in_array($this->socket, $this->read))
            {
                for($i = 0; $i < $this->max_clients;$i++)
                {
                    //Null clients mean their connection has not been accepted.
                    if($this->connected_clients[$i] == null)
                    {
                        $this->connected_clients[$i] = socket_accept($this->socket);
                        if(socket_getpeername($this->connected_clients[$i], $ip, $port))
                        {
                            if($this->checkBanned($ip) == true)
                            {
                                echo "Connection from $ip was blocked.\n";
                                socket_write($this->connected_clients[$i], "You are banned from using the ISH for the following reason:");
                                $reason = $this->getBanReason($ip);
                                socket_write($this->connected_clients[$i], "\r\n");
                                socket_write($this->connected_clients[$i], $reason);
                                socket_close($this->connected_clients[$i]);
                            }else
                            {
                                echo "Connection from $ip was accepted.\n";
                                $this->send($this->connected_clients[$i], "Connection accepted!\n");
                                $this->send($this->connected_clients[$i], "\r\n");
                                $this->send($this->connected_clients[$i], "Retrieving user data.\n");
                                $this->getUserData($ip);
                                $this->send($this->connected_clients[$i], "\r\n");
                                $this->send($this->connected_clients[$i], "Welcome ".$this->username);
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }


            for($i = 0; $i < $this->max_clients; $i++)
            {
                if(in_array($this->connected_clients[$i], $this->read))
                {
                    $input = socket_read($this->connected_clients[$i], 1024);
                    if($input == null)
                    {
                        if(socket_getpeername($this->connected_clients[$i], $ip, $port))
                        {
                            echo "$ip disconnected from port $port.\n";
                        }
                        socket_close($this->connected_clients[$i]);
                        unset($this->connected_clients[$i]);
                    }
                }                   
            }
            if($input == "login")
            {
                echo "LOGIN CALLED!";
            }else
            {
                echo $input;
            }
        }
    }
}


?>
```

The input handler is at the bottom:

```
if($input == "login")
{   
    echo "LOGIN CALLED!";           
}else
{
    echo $input;            
}
```

Comment: At Stackoverflow we want to know your *problem*, not a manual on your system.

In fact you should reduce the whole thing down to a simple test case (without all the database part), for example twenty lines or less, and focus more on what codes have you tried to read inputs.

Otherwise, even after extensive edit, it may still be closed by others.

Comment: Btw, since you are actually creating your code please remember that mysql and mysqli extensions are deprecated and should be replaced by PDO.

Comment: @LelioFaieta MySQLi is [not actually deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) (yet)... but I don't like it either ;)

Comment: Are you a Java programmer? Why are you writing your own telnet server?

Comment: @symcbean It's for a test on my server, to see how far I can take PHP. I just thought it would be cool to have.

Comment: @Sheepy Sorry, I did not want to be too vague, or miss any important part of the code. I'm somewhat new to PHP sockets, I did not know what was needed and what wasn't.